# IE 11 and Enhanced Protection Mode and custom BHO : is there some debug info?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, internet-explorer-11, bho

I need to install my custom BHO (written in C#) on Internet Explorer with Enhanced Protection Mode.

According to this [MS blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2012/03/23/understanding-ie10-enhanced-protected-mode-network-security-addons-cookies-metro-desktop.aspx), in Win7 all I need to do is use a 64bits binary, but it does not seem enough as the BHO is still blocked. Is there any debug log I can use to know what the exact issue is ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You [should not write IE extensions in Managed Code](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2014/04/10/do-not-write-browser-extensions-toolbars-bhos-and-activex-in-managed-dotnet-code.aspx).
2. You need to register your code in both 32bit and 64bit mode. IE will not load your extension if it is only registered in one bitness. To quote the article you linked:

> In order to be EPM-compatible, Toolbars and BHOs must be available in
>   32bit and 64bit flavors, to avoid toolbars or other UI appearing and
>   disappearing as you navigate between zones that run at different
>   bitnesses.

Comment: Thanks ! This unblocked my BHO.

Comment: Do you mean have the build action set to 'Any CPU' or do we need two versions built specifically for one bitness or the other?

Comment: Neither. You should build for AnyCPU, but your COM registration needs to be in both 32bit and 64bit hives. But to reiterate, you should not be using .NET for this task at all.